# Getting estimate and CI for dummy variable in linear model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data, linear-model, factor-analysis

I have a linear model based on some variables (age, gaming and tasks) on response time.
It looks like this:

```
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) 15.69493    5.33508   2.942   0.0048 **
Age          0.02475    0.14071   0.176   0.8610   
Task2       -0.67334    3.46548  -0.194   0.8467   
Task3        1.03528    3.46548   0.299   0.7663   
Gamingyes    1.88009    3.31765   0.567   0.5733
```

I understand that R chooses a dummy variable, in this case it is Task 1, as the intercept value and that the estimates for the rest is the difference from Task 1. But are you able to get estimate and CI for Task 1 without breaking the linear model. Because, what would be the reference variable if I took task 1 out of the equation as the dummy variable?

I have tried using relevel and the "- 1" parameter, without success.
So is this just how it is - for a linear model. That it has to have a dummy variable, and that the rest are the estimate difference for this dummy variable?

Comment: Try `lm(. ~ 0 + age + task + Gamingyes)`

Comment: Your answer helped me to understand what I need and how to interpret the results. Thank you. Please post again as an answer and I'll accept it.